# SQL - How to sum my calculated column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle, I'm trying to sum my calculated column, but I don't know how

```
SELECT a.ID, a.grade_code,
ROUND((sum(a.grade)/b.quantity)*b.percentage/100,2) as promedio 
FROM grade a
INNER JOIN distri_grade b
ON b.grade_code = a.grade_code
group by a.ID, a.grade_code, b.quantity, b.percentage
order by a.ID, a.grade_code
```

Result:

[image]

What I'm looking for:

```
ID - PROMEDIO
1  - 71.81
```

Comment: Remove `a.grade_code` from the `SELECT`, `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your question.  Your query wouldn't produce just 2 columns.  Perhaps you could include sample data as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be something like this:

```
SELECT g.ID, 
       ROUND(sum( (g.grade / dg.quantity) * dg.percentage / 100), 2) as promedio 
FROM grade g INNER JOIN
     distri_grade dg
     ON dg.grade_code = g.grade_code
group by g.ID
order by g.ID;
```

If you want one row per `ID`, then that is the only column that should go in the `GROUP BY`.  I am speculating a bit on what the formula you are looking for is.  In any case, all the columns used need to be arguments to the aggregation function `sum()`.

Note:  table aliases that are abbreviations for table names are much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, remove the `quantity` and `percentage` fields from the `group by` clause.  Also add parentheses around the entire `sum` clause:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.grade_code,
     round(sum((a.grade/b.quantity)*(b.percentage/100)),2) as promedio 
FROM grade a
     INNER JOIN distri_grade b
          ON b.grade_code = a.grade_code
group by a.ID, a.grade_code
order by a.ID, a.grade_code
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen -- Yes, you could be correct, but I'm not 100% sure, depends on the desired results.  The question is a little unclear at this point to be honest.  That query would not have produced that result...

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that you want this:

```
SELECT
    a.ID,
    ROUND( sum(a.grade) / min(b.quantity) * min(b.percentage) / 100, 2 ) as promedio 
FROM grade a INNER JOIN distri_grade b ON b.grade_code = a.grade_code
group by a.ID
```

It appears to me from what you were attempting that all the values from `distri_grade` (aka `b`) are fixed for all rows attached to a single `ID`. When these are constants it is true algebraically that `sum(a.grade / QUANTITY * PERCENTAGE) = sum(a.grade) / QUANTITY * PERCENTAGE` because of the the distributive property of multiplication over addition. In SQL the way to pull out these "constant" values over the group is to use a dummy aggregation like `min()` or `max()`. And although you could just wrap the summation around the whole expression this method probably has an advantage (depending on the datatypes involved) in numerical accuracy by doing the division and multiplication only a single time. Note also to be careful with integer division since I'm guessing that your three columns are potentially all whole numbers.